# How to make .net 6.0 application to support multiple languages

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to translate my application to multiple languages. The application is .Net 6.0 - MVC.
I have never done this before, however, my idea is to compile the application several times with a different language, then to add a href to a specific path(folder /en/).

The application has several static paragraphs with few pages(Home,Projects,About,Contact,Calculator)

What is the best and easiest solution?
Thank you in advance.